# how to check the else statement in if else condition

Tags: java

```
package react;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Intputfromuser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        System.out.println("enter a number to compare with number 5 ");
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=input.nextInt();
        if(a==2)
        {
            System.out.println("U Have Entered The same value");
        }
        else if(a<2)
        {
            System.out.println("Ur number is Smaller than 2");
        }
        else if(a>2)
        {
            System.out.println("U Have Entered the number Greater than ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("U Have Enterer Invalid Input");
        }

    }
}
```

how to get only integer from the user if the user enters any thing except integer then else statement should run

Comment: Parse the input to an integer, put a try-catch around it, and put what you would put in your else in your catch block

Comment: Did you try running this and entering a non-integer?

Comment: What has `2` got to do with anything? The prompt indicates to compare against the integer value of `5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative. Be sure to read the comments in code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Open a keyboard input stream. There is no need to close 
       this stream. The JVM will do that automatically when the
       application closes.               */
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String val = "";    // Used to store User input:
    // User Prompt with 'quit' capability and entry validation:
    while (val.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to compare with number 5 (q to quit): -> ");
        val = input.nextLine().trim(); // Trim in case just a whitespace(s) was entered.
        // Was 'q' for quit supplied?
        if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            /* Yes...then quit. Returning out of main() effectively 
               closes this particular application:             */
            System.out.println("Quiting - Bye Bye");
            return;
        }
        // Validate Entry:
        /* Is entry a string representation of a signed or unsigned Integer 
           value and does the supplied value fall within the relm of an int? */
        if (!val.matches("-?\\d+") || (Long.parseLong(val) < Integer.MIN_VALUE) || 
                                      (Long.parseLong(val) > Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            // No...Inform User and allow to try again:
            System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Entry! {" + val + ") Try again..." 
                               + System.lineSeparator());
            val = "";   // Empty variable to ensure re-loop:
        }
    }
    
    // If you make it to this point in code, the User input was valid!
    // Now parse the String numerical value to an int:
    int a = Integer.parseInt(val);
    
    /* At this point, there are only three usable conditions:
       Equal To, Less Than, and Greater Than (validity has
       already been handled within the `while` loop:     */
    
    // Equal To:
    if (a == 5) {
        System.out.println("You have entered The same value.");
    }
    // Less Than:
    else if (a < 5) {
        System.out.println("Your number is smaller than 5.");
    }
    // Greater Than:
    else {
        System.out.println("You have entered a number greater than 5.");
    }
    // DONE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input.nextLine() instead and parse it to a String.

To avoid a ParseException, surround it by using a `try { ... } catch() { ... }` block.

In the catch block you can e.g. print a message informing the user of the wrong input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter a number to compare with number 5 ");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userInput = s.nextLine();

    try {
        int option = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        if (option == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("U Have Entered The same value");
        }
        else if (option < 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Ur number is Smaller than 2");
        }
        else if (option > 2)
        {
            System.out.println("U Have Entered the number Greater than 2");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
}
```

Hope this sort of helped!

Comment: actually, this won't work for an obvious reason. Can you spot the flaw in your logic?

Comment: @Stultuske Indeed, I have...

Comment: don't forget to update the explanation at the end of your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also create method to collect input and make it inside loop like this:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("enter a number to compare with number 5: ");

        int userInput = getInteger();


        if (userInput == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("U Have Entered The same value");
        }
        else if (userInput < 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Ur number is Smaller than 2");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("U Have Entered the number Greater than 2");
        }
    }

    static int getInteger() {
        boolean correct = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = 0;
        do {
            try {
                userInput = input.nextInt();
                correct = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input");
                System.out.println("Please try again: ");
            } finally {
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }
        while (!correct);
        input.close();
        return userInput;
    }
}
```

Important note with scanner.nextInt() or scanner.nextDouble()
you need to call scanner.nextLine() after that to clear input. Otherwise you will end up with endless loop.

Comment: why do you change the functionality? according to the question, there is no repeat if you enter an invalid value

Comment: Also, calling `input.close()` on `System.in` is not a good idea. Try calling `getInteger()` twice and you'll see.